# multi-table mysql/php query with two outputs to an array

Tags: php, mysql, xml, opencart

This is gonna take a minute to explain, sorry.

This bit of code is part of an xml vqmod for opencart that exports order data from selected orders to an excel spreadsheet.  For the most part it works fine.   There is one hitch though, if there is a record with more than one advanced_coupon listed for a particular order it will crap out.

I'm sure I need to add an array for the output of that and it's related field for the discount amount, but I'm not sure how to do that.  I'm new to php/MySQL, but learn quickly.  If I could get pointed in the right direction that would be awesome.

I'm new here, but could not find similar in search.  Thanks again.

Here is the pertinent bit of code:

```
    // The actual options data
    $i += 1;
    $j = 0;
      $query  = "SELECT o.*, op.name, op.model, op.order_product_id, op.quantity, op.price, op.total AS ptotal, op.product_id, op.tax, (SELECT amount FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "sales_promotion_history WHERE order_id = o.order_id) AS sales_promo_amount, (SELECT title FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total ot WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'sales_promotion') AS sales_promo_code, (SELECT value FROM order_total ott WHERE ott.order_id = o.order_id AND ott.code = 'shipping') AS shipping_cost, (SELECT name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status os WHERE os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id) AS `order_status`, (SELECT ot.value FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total ot WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'sub_total') AS sub_total, (SELECT ot.value FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total ot WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'credit') AS store_credit, (SELECT ot.title FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total ot WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'voucher') AS gift_code, (SELECT ot.text FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total ot WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'voucher') AS gift_value, (SELECT title FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total ot WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'advanced_coupon') AS advanced_coupon_code, (SELECT amount FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "advanced_coupon_history WHERE order_id = o.order_id) AS ac_amount, (SELECT ot.title FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total ot WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'coupon') AS coupon_code, (SELECT ot.text FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total ot WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'coupon') AS coupon_value FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o inner join `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_product` op on o.order_id=op.order_id  WHERE o.order_id IN ( ".$orderid." ) order by o.order_id";

    $result = $database->query( $query );
    foreach ($result->rows as $row) {
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['order_id'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['date_added'] );            
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['firstname'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['lastname'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['payment_method'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['shipping_firstname'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['shipping_lastname'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['shipping_company'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['shipping_address_1'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['shipping_address_2'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['shipping_city'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['shipping_postcode'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['shipping_zone'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['shipping_method'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['shipping_cost'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['total'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['model'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['name'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['quantity'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['price'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['ptotal'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['tax'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['sub_total'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['store_credit'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['order_status'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['store_name'] );

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $product = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($row['product_id']);
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $product['cost'] );

        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, trim(next(explode('(',$row['coupon_code'])),')') );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['coupon_value'] );

        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, trim(next(explode('(',$row['gift_code'])),')') );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['gift_value'] );

        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['advanced_coupon_code'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['ac_amount'] );

        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['sales_promo_code'] );
        $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['sales_promo_amount'] );


        // works fine don't need $order_options = array();
        //$order_str = array();
        //$order_options = $this->getOrderOptions($row['order_id'], $row['order_product_id']);
        //foreach($order_options as $order_option){
        //  $order_str[] = $order_option['name'].':'.$order_option['value'];
        //}
        //$worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, implode('@@@' , $order_str));
        //works fine don't need 

        $i += 1;
        $j = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query you can replace this part:

```
(SELECT title FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total ot WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'advanced_coupon') AS advanced_coupon_code,
```

to this one

```
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`title`) FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total ot WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'advanced_coupon' GROUP BY ot.order_id) AS advanced_coupon_code,
```

Or, if you are trust me, just replace your `$query = ". . . ";` string with my variant:

```
$query  = "
    SELECT 
        o.*, 
        op.name, 
        op.model, 
        op.order_product_id, 
        op.quantity, 
        op.price, 
        op.total AS ptotal, 
        op.product_id, 
        op.tax, 
        (
            SELECT amount 
            FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "sales_promotion_history 
            WHERE order_id = o.order_id
        ) AS sales_promo_amount, 
        (
            SELECT title 
            FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total ot 
            WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'sales_promotion'
        ) AS sales_promo_code, 
        (
            SELECT value 
            FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total ott 
            WHERE ott.order_id = o.order_id AND ott.code = 'shipping'
        ) AS shipping_cost, 
        (
            SELECT name 
            FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status os 
            WHERE os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id
        ) AS `order_status`, 
        (
            SELECT ot.value 
            FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total ot 
            WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'sub_total'
        ) AS sub_total, 
        (
            SELECT ot.value 
            FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total ot 
            WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'credit'
        ) AS store_credit, 
        (
            SELECT ot.title 
            FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total ot 
            WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'voucher'
        ) AS gift_code, 
        (
            SELECT ot.text 
            FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total ot 
            WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'voucher'
        ) AS gift_value, 
        (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`title`) 
            FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total ot 
            WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'advanced_coupon' 
            GROUP BY ot.order_id
        ) AS advanced_coupon_code,
        (
            SELECT amount 
            FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "advanced_coupon_history 
            WHERE order_id = o.order_id
        ) AS ac_amount, 
        (
            SELECT ot.title 
            FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total ot 
            WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'coupon'
        ) AS coupon_code, 
        (
            SELECT ot.text 
            FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total ot 
            WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'coupon'
        ) AS coupon_value 
    FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o 
    INNER JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_product` op ON o.order_id=op.order_id 
    WHERE o.order_id IN ( ".$orderid." ) 
    ORDER BY o.order_id";
```

Comment: I did trust you, as I had done the same neatening up of the code on my end! It mostly worked, but I had to make one change.   I had to treat the ac_amount SELECT the same way as the advanced_coupon_code.  If one had multiple values, they both would.

With Sergey giving me a great example of the GROUP_CONCAT it was really easy!

Since the ac_amount is a number rather than string, is there a way I can add them up or keep them numerical so the spreadsheet can?  I think I could do it with SUM, but I'm super new to SQL still so it will take a sec to get it ;-)

Comment: Yes, SUM function can help you. It is aggregate function too, like GROUP_CONCAT, so best way to use it is using combination with "GROUP BY".

Comment: I did the SUM part yesterday and it worked like a champ.  Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

try to replace:

```
 $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['advanced_coupon_code'] );
```

with:

```
 foreach( $row['advanced_coupon_code'] as $code )
 {
   $worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $code );
 }
```

Comment: @Benjamin  Thank you but that still gives a blank excel as output for queries with multiple advanced_coupon_codes and when there is only a single code listed it will skip them entirely and put the sales_promo_code in the advanced_coupon_code column of the file.